# Increment/Decrement byte (char) in c++ with over/under-flow

Tags: c++, byte, overflow, increment, underflow

What is the best way to increment/decrement a byte in c++ while taking into consideration the overflow and underflow? For example, I have:

```
char c = random byte;
c += 0xB;
```

In case c <= 0xF4, this will work well, but any value above that would cause an overflow. Likewise, if it was c -= 0xB; and c < 0xB, an underflow would occur.

Let's say c =  0xFF, after the addition, will it be 0xA? Likewise with the underflow, if c = 0, will the result be 0xF5?

Also, for some odd, reasons, when I increase specific numbers, weird results occur. For example, if I increase 0x0 by 0xA, using the code:

```
c = (c + 0xA) & 0xFF;
```

the result is: 0x0D 0x0A and not just 0x0A... just as shown in the following image:
[image: Increment Issue]

While all the rest of the bytes increase correctly.

Comment: I can't spot a single increment or decrement operation.

Comment: I'm not sure I used the correct word to describe the operation since I'm not a native speaker, but this is what I meant with increment: c = (c + 0xA). I also just edited the code since I forgot to change variables used in the code appropriately. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Are you trying to use this for encryption? Maybe you're wanting to use [exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) instead.

Comment: @BraveHeart That's called _addition_ (and the opposite is _subtraction_). Increment/decrement is usually used when a value is added/subtracted 1.

Comment: usually the architecture will have a status byte to signal over- /under-flow

Comment: At least as far as the `0A` it seems very clear that you're on a Windows system, and that your file I/O is helpfully translating a `\n` to `\r\n` (native end of line indicator) for you.

Comment: Use `unsigned char` if you want values greater than `0x7f` and bitwise operations. Otherwise, the behaviour is sketchily defined at best.

Comment: Oh yea. my bad. @FredLarson Yes, I'm using this for encryption. I'll look into xor'ing, but is there a way for this current method to work? (increasing the value of a char while taking over/under-flow into consideration).

Comment: @MarkB is there a way to stop the system from translating \n to \r\n?

Comment: @Brave Heart Yes, you can open the stream in binary mode. The method varies depending on the precise file I/O method you're using. Also, what do you mean by "take into consideration". Do you want it to fail if it would over/underflow? Or would you like a different behavior?

Comment: @MarkB writing the file in binary mode seemed to be the fix. Thanks for the advice. Please write your answer as an answer below so that I can pick it as the correct answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can at least explain your results with `0x0 by 0xA`: On Windows, a newline in text files is typically represented as `\r\n` rather than `\n` and the file I/O functions will helpfully make this translation for you. In this case you don't desire the conversion though so you could open the file in binary mode which will inhibit the automatic conversion.

As for handling overflow, if you are able to use `unsigned char` instead of `char`, it's guaranteed to have well-defined modulo arithmetic for overflow and underflow.

If you need to handle signed over/under flow you're going to have to carefully code up all the logic you want.